# I want to see these all products in a single table.... but it is showing in different tables for each product

Tags: php, html

I want to see these all products in a single table.... but it is showing in different tables for each product. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a01sk.png)

```
  <?php foreach($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $result) { ?>

     <table border="2" cellspacing="5">
        <tr><td>Product Code</td>
        <td>Product Image</td>
        <td>Product Name</td>
        <td>Product Price</td>
        <td>Product Quantity</td></tr>

        <tr style="background: #e0e545;">
          <td style="padding: 14px;"><?php echo $result['code']; ?></td>
          <td style="padding: 14px;"><?php echo $result['image']; ?></td>
          <td style="padding: 14px;"><?php echo $result['name']; ?></td>
          <td style="padding: 14px;"><?php echo $result['price']; ?></td>
          <td style="padding: 14px;"><?php echo $result['quantity']; ?></td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
          <td><?php print $_SESSION['total']?></td>
        </tr>

     </table>

  <?php }   ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You basically answered your own question. You are generating a HTML table for each product. Try putting the for loop within the `<table>` element. Also, I recommend using `<th>` for the table headers, as it was meant for that.

```
<table border="2" cellspacing="5">
<tr>
    <th>Product Code</th>
    <th>Product Image</th>
    <th>Product Name</th>
    <th>Product Price</th>
    <th>Product Quantity</th>
</tr>

<?php
foreach($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $result) {
?>
<tr style="background: #e0e545;">
    <td style="padding: 14px;"><?php echo $result['code']; ?></td>
    <td style="padding: 14px;"><?php echo $result['image']; ?></td>
    <td style="padding: 14px;"><?php echo $result['name']; ?></td>
    <td style="padding: 14px;"><?php echo $result['price']; ?></td>
    <td style="padding: 14px;"><?php echo $result['quantity']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>

<tr>
    <td><?php print $_SESSION['total']?>

    </td>
</tr>
```

Try using this code instead. I put the PHP tags around each table row and I made the top table row cells with `<th>` instead of `<td>`